# Extracting matches with Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to extract the following string `RL2.OPT.TEST.01`­ from this one `­a lot of text...[RL2.OPT.TEST.01]<some more text`­. Basically there can be anything before the `­RL2.`­ but it always begins with `­RL2.`­, and always finish by either `­]`­, `­<`­, or a space.

I tried with the following regex: `m/RL2\..*[\s<\]]+?$/g`
but even if it finds a match for the string `­-- [RL2.OPT.TEST.01]`­, it does not work for `­-- [RL2.OPT.TEST.01] some more text`­.

I need an array of all the resultings matches in the large string I have. I think I should also mention that this string has a lot of newline characters, but never in the middle of the strings I am trying to extract.

Any clue about what is wrong with my regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negated character class and remove the end of the line anchor `$`

```
m/RL2\.[^\s<\]]*/g
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tD4yN3/3)

`[^\s<\]]*` Negated character class which matches any character but not of space or `<` or `]` zero or more times.

Comment: Thank you it did the trick! Will accept the answer in 7min (my account is brand new).